# Lower resulting weights, for substrate as is, upon benchmarking as compared to the weights file provided

Tags: weight, benchmark

We are using a machine, similar to reference: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/5848, to benchmark our runtime.
To ascertain that our machine is close enough to the reference, we ran substrate (branch: polkadot-v0.9.16, commit: 19162e43be45817b44c7d48e50d03f074f60fbf4) benchmarks as is for the runtime.
The resulting weights we got were about 20% lower than what is specified in substrate (in the respective weights.rs files), indicating that our machine is 20% faster than the reference.

Is this expected? Should we get a slower machine? Downclock this one?
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `cargo build --profile production` turns on fat LTO and that's what we've been switching to using for all the benchmarking weight runs. That might explain some of the difference you're seeing. Bear in mind it's not an exact science: one would not expect to get it spot on - you can see from some of the statemint weight PRs that they move about a little from one release to the next.

Comment: We updated the weights recently and compiler flags.  
I think that was after `v0.9.16`. Could please try again on master?

Answer (score 1):

Within 20% sounds fine. It's all about getting the order of magnitude right ( [the big O complexity notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#:%7E:text=Big%20O%20notation%20is%20a,a%20particular%20value%20or%20infinity.) ).
We have built in some machine benchmarks into substrate so that we can tell if our machine spec is roughly in line with the parity benchmark machines that the weights are generated on.

Now that [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/11198) has landed you can run this:

```
cargo run --profile production benchmark machine --dev
```

These are the results of master at 1e0807fb477 on one of our benchmarking machines:

```
+----------+----------------+-------+------+
| Category | Function       | Score | Unit |
+----------+----------------+-------+------+
| CPU      | BLAKE2-256     | 1029  | MB/s |
+----------+----------------+-------+------+
| CPU      | SR25519 Verify | 665.3 | KB/s |
+----------+----------------+-------+------+
| Memory   | Copy           | 14697 | MB/s |
+----------+----------------+-------+------+
| Disk     | Seq Write      | 472   | MB/s |
+----------+----------------+-------+------+
| Disk     | Rnd Write      | 212   | MB/s |
+----------+----------------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Incidentally these stats don't care if it's a `--release` build or a `--profile production` build (the latter takes considerably longer to compile but should be used for running benchmarks)